# I read in a book that if you pass an array of size 0 as an argument to the function of Functional Interface then it will throw

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, expression

I read in a book that if you pass an array of size 0 as an argument to the function of Functional Interface then it will result in a checked exception and compiler will issue an warning.So you have to create an user defined exception and throw it the abstract function definition in the functional interface for the code to run properly.
I tried to run this code and its working fine:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface DoubleArray{
    double func(int[] n);
}
    public class GenDemo {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            DoubleArray ref=(n)->{
                double avg=0;
                for(int i=0;i<n.length;i++)
                    avg=avg+n[i];
                avg=avg/n.length;
                return avg;
                };

                int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5};
                System.out.println(ref.func(arr));
                System.out.println(ref.func(new int[0]));
          }
}
```

Output:
3.0
NaN

What is this "NaN" ?

What book expects is something like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface DoubleArray{
    double func(int[] n)throws EmptyArrayException;
}
class EmptyArrayException extends Exception{
    EmptyArrayException(){
    super("Empty Array passed");
    }
}
public class GenDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoubleArray ref=(n)->{
            double avg=0;
            if(n.length==0)
                throw new EmptyArrayException();
            for(int i=0;i<n.length;i++)
                avg=avg+n[i];
            avg=avg/n.length;
            return avg;
            };

            int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5};
            System.out.println(ref.func(new int[0]));
        }
}
```

But even without doing this the code is working fine.
As per my understanding checked exceptions are the exception that compiler checks for before compilation and it will give compile time error.
So above written doesn't throws any checked exception it executes smoothly. Then what is the point to throw a user defined exception for null array ref.
Documentation says that if a lambda exp throws a checked exception then that exception must be compatible with the exception(s) listed in the throws clause of the abstract method in the functional interface.

Any answers please?
Thanks.

Comment: What book? Sounds wrong to me.

Comment: `NaN` is "Not a Number".

Comment: ... and it occurs here because of the division by zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a function or method **that throws a checked exception**, you have to **surround your code with *try/catch* or add a *throw* declaration** to pass the task of exception handling to the caller of your code. It is a **design decision** if you use:

- a **checked exception**, e. g. `double func(int[] n) throws Exception;`,
- an unchecked exception, e. g. `double func(int[] n) throws RuntimeException;`,
- a **special return value** like `null` or [`NaN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN) (*Not a Number*) or
- [`Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) as return value instead of `T`.

A **checked exception is less error-prone but requires more code** than a special return value. An unchecked exception leaves it to the user to surround your code with *try/catch* or not. Since Java 8, you can also use `Optional<T>` which is also less error-prone and which requires more code than a special return value, but less code than a checked exception.

In your examples, the average of all the values of an array is calculated. Assuming, in your first example the average of the averages of both arrays should be calculated (instead separately calculating the averages of the two arrays), you might write `System.out.println((ref.func(arr) + ref.func(new int[0])) / 2);`. The result would be `NaN` (because `3.0 + NaN` is `NaN` and `NaN / 2` is `NaN`) instead of `3.0`. Without a checked exception you would have easily overlooked that there might be an empty array of which no average can be calculated and which should therefor be skipped when calculating the average of the averages.

Here is your simplified **example** that contains both, a function that returns **`NaN`** when the divisor is `0` and the **equivalent** function that throws a **checked exception** when the divisor is `0`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Nanable {
    double average(double total, int divisor);
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface Checked {
    double average(double total, int divisor) throws Exception;
}

public class GenDemo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // NaN-able (can return NaN)
        Nanable nanableImpl = (total, divisor) -> {
            return total / divisor;
        };
        System.out.println(nanableImpl.average(15d, 5));
        System.out.println(nanableImpl.average(0, 0));

        // checked (can throw a checked exception)
        Checked checkedImpl = (total, divisor) -> {
            if (divisor == 0) throw new Exception("Divisor must not be 0");
            return total / divisor;
        };
        try {
            System.out.println(checkedImpl.average(15d, 5));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // can never happen because divisor != 0
        }
        try {
            checkedImpl.average(0, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(Double.NaN); // expected
        }

    }

}
```